# Problem opening pdfs on Google Chrome

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, pdf, embedded, adobe-reader

I have recently started to use Google Chrome again and noticed that it was having difficulties with opening pdfs. (I'm reading scientific journals) When I click on the link to open the pdf, it would just display a blank page.

Things I tried

1. refreshing the page. (f5, pressing the refresh button) - although sometimes, it will open
2. reinstalling Chrome (v5), upgrading to Beta and dev channels (now on Version 6.) 
   same problem in all versions.
3. reinstalling adobe reader
4. disabling the adobe reader plugin then re-enabling it.

However, I did stumble upon a fix which is to resize the window.

After I restore and maximize the window, pdfs are displayed. but this is rather annoying having to constantly resize my windows to open a pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Adobe Reader 9.3.0 download from Adobe's site isn't the latest available version.  Try checking for updates under the help menu and see if updating to 9.3.3 changes anything.

You can also try an alternative PDF reader, such as foxit (which has a PDF plugin for chrome).

Were you always running the beta version of Chrome, or did you just upgrade now to see if it addressed the issue?

Comment: I have 9.3.3 and I'd rather not install another pdf reader seeing as its a company laptop. I upgraded to see if that was the issue, but I noticed the same thing in the stable version as well.

Comment: You might be able to use an alternative portable PDF reader instead, this would mean that you don't have to install the application. Sumatra PDF is a lightweight PDF reader which can be run as a portable application, more details here: http://portableapps.com/apps/office/sumatra_pdf_portable